# How to get variable name from another module in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, global-variables

When I execute `test.py`

`tests.py`

```
class A():
    def prints(self,*f):
        for j in f:
            for i in globals():
                if globals()[i]==j:
                    print(f'{i}={j}')
            

s=3;id=2 #it will discard when executing main.py
a=A()
a.prints(s,id)
```

I get the output:

```
s=3 id=2
```

But if I import from another program

`main.py`

```
from tests import A
if __name__ =='__main__':
    
    id=3
    s=1
    a=A()
    a.prints(s,id)
```

I get nothing.

How do I get the same output as the former one?

Comment: `if globals()[i]==j:` will look at the globals in `tests`, not in `main`. Probably just pass the namespace explicitly to this function

Comment: Do you mean pass `globals()[]`  in `a.prints()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `prints` function does not scale. what happens if there are a multiple variables with the same value you supply to your function?

This is what you want

```
In [1]: import sys

In [2]: class A():
   ...:     def prints(self,*f):                                                                        ...:         # get the caller's frame with sys._getframe
   ...:         frame = sys._getframe(1)
   ...:         # get all variables in the caller's namespace
   ...:         all_vars = frame.f_locals
   ...:         for j in f:
   ...:             for i in all_vars:
   ...:                 if all_vars[i]==j:
   ...:                     print(f'{i}={j}')
   ...:

In [3]: a = A()

In [4]: a.prints(a)
a=<__main__.A object at 0x763c377790>
```

Comment: What I did here was hack into the frame calling the `prints` function. If it is called inside a function, it has access to all variables defined inside the function.

Comment: I know this program can't distinct the different variable with same value.Probably I need to get the variable's unique address and pass it as a parameter.

Comment: Oh you can just pass the name of the variable

Comment: But when `s=3;id=3`  And I pass  `a.prints(s)` ,its output is `s=3,id=3`  not `s=3`

Comment: exactly my point, this is because it found 2 variables with the same value `3` an printed them both out.

Comment: when you pass in `s` into your function, you are actually passing in `3` which the variable `s` represents.

Comment: @Jr.dective fundamentally what you are trying to do here is not really sound and you shouldn't organize your code this way. Unless you have a really compelling reason, and there are some specific circumstances where this might be required - e.g. writing a debugger - you shoulnd't be doing this to begin with

Comment: Actually, I created a module,and I want to display it by rewriting the build-in print function to debug it. Thank you, I figure out how to solve this problem.

Comment: @Dave if  I put string directly in `a.prints("s,other_variable...")` and use split function in `test.py` ,then it could avoid multiple variable with same value

Comment: after the `print(f'{i}={j}')` line, add `break`